# Who was that guy in the movie 'Spy' 2015?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, spy

I recently watched the movie 'Spy' released in 2015 and at one point of movie where Susan (Melissa McCarthy) was in Rome to track and report Rayna (played by Rose Byrne) mission and she saves Rayna from a **guy** who had put something in Rayna's drink at the Casino to dissolve her throat, which she finds out beforehand. She has that guy killed outside the casino.

This anonymous guy claims to be a businessman from outside Rome but the movie doesn't tell which side he's on. He was neither from CIA nor De Luka's organization (the main intermediary who connects Rayna to terrorist organization for the nuclear bomb deals) because they would both need Rayna alive so they could locate the nuclear bomb the information to which only Rayna knows.

What was the motivation of this killer? Who was he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [guy](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2046855/) (or as I like to think of him, [Jared from Silicon Valley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Valley_(TV_series)) was just a random assassin.  Basically his character was just a way to show that Rayna in over-her-head, despite her arrogance.  She made a lot of enemies, so there were lots of parties interested in seeing her dead.  She was smart enough to surround herself with body-guards, but apparently wasn't all that experienced at picking talent.  Combine that with her tendency to kill underlings who fail her, and eventually her security team was staffed entirely by CIA agents.

Also, Jared's assassination attempt was a device that forced Susan to have to save the life of a woman who she would have rather seen killed, allowing the plot to go in an even zanier trajectory.